# How to compare datetime in ms format at a postgresql table using python?

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a Postgresql database wherein the created_at data is available in milliseconds format. I am looking for the records which got created in last 1 hour. However, I am not getting any result. When I tried from a DB client (DBeaver) and do the comparision, I am getting the output. What should I change to get appropriate result while running this in a python script?

```py
conn = psycopg2.connect(
        host="db_server_name",
        database="db_name",
        user="db_user_name",
        password="db_pass")
cursor = conn.cursor()
last_1_hour = round(time.time()*1000) - 3600000
query = "SELECT pkey FROM projects WHERE created_at >=" + str(last_1_hour)
cursor.execute(query)
pkey_result = cursor.fetchall()
print(len(pkey_result))
```

I have tried the below from the database client, which gave proper result. However, when I tried running the same from a python script, it didn't work. I followed the below options as well.

The below select query is with a hard-coded value of a bigint comparison.

```
select pkey, created_at from projects where created_at >= 1697287784000
```

The below query is by converting into a datetime format for comparison.

```
SELECT pkey FROM projects WHERE to_char(to_timestamp(created_at/1000),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.MS') >= to_char(to_timestamp(1697264982920/1000),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.MS')
```

Have also tried parameterized processing as below at python script. It also didn't help.

```
str_time_in_millis = "1697287784000"
cursor.execute("SELECT pkey FROM projects WHERE created_at >= %s", (str_time_in_millis,))
```

Also, converted to utc and performed the comparison for last 24 hours. Though there is a matching record, getting result as 0 for the record count (pkey_result) instead of 1.

```py
dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(round(1697287784000 / 1000.0), tz=datetime.timezone.utc)
cursor.execute("SELECT pkey FROM projects WHERE to_timestamp(created_at/1000) >= %s", (datetime.datetime.strftime(dt,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"),))
pkey_result = cursor.fetchall()
print(len(pkey_result))
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Start by using a parameterised query like every single tutorial, the docs and 99% of the stackoverflow answers recommend? Then use an actual timestamp-type in your variable rather than a float.

Comment: I also tried "SELECT pkey FROM projects WHERE created_at >= now() - interval '1 hours'". However, I ended up with "HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts."

Comment: Can you share the table definition from Postgres please (`\d projects` in the psql console).

Comment: Or run a `select created_at, pg_typeof(created_at) from projects limit 1;`

Comment: it is bigint type. At DDL, it was defined as created_at int8 NULL

Comment: I tried to convert both of them in same format and tried to perform the comparison
compare_hrs = pd.Timestamp.now() - pd.Timedelta('1 hours')
"SELECT pkey FROM projects WHERE to_char(to_timestamp(created_at/1000),'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') >=" + compare_hrs.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M%S")
Getting the error as below
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "17"
LINE 1: ...created_at/1000),'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') >=2023-10-14 17:49

Comment: 1) Add the clarifying information as **update to question text** not in the comments. 2) Using [Parameter passing](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries). 3) Use `timestamptz` field for `created_at`.

Comment: If you want to stick with `integers` then: `... created_at >= round(extract(epoch from now() - '1 hour'::interval)) * 1000`. I would say the saner choice going forward is to work with  `timestamptz` data type in Postgres, then you get all the benefits of datetime handling and math.

Comment: Agreed... But, think about a bigint comparison of postgresql using python. select pkey, created_at from projects where created_at >= 1697287784000 works fine from database client. But, why it is not working while executing from python? The timestamp, timestamptz conversion also didn't help in rendering the result.

Answer (score 0):

Got the help from one of my colleague. The below helped me to get the results rendered.

```py
str_time_in_millis = "1697287784000"
cursor.execute(f"SELECT pkey FROM projects WHERE created_at >= {str_time_in_millis}")
```